# Life is filled with sources of stress, many/ much of which

Tags: grammar

I am wondering if it is possible to use both forms or not.

Stress is uncountable while source is countable.

1. Life is filled with sources of stress, much of which cannot be avoided.
2. Life is filled with sources of stress, many of which cannot be avoided.

Comment: Are you avoiding stress or the sources of stress?

Comment: My refrigerator is filled with jugs of milk [many of which are glass / much of which is spoiled].

Answer (score -1):

Yeah,"stress" is uncountable when it means "Emotional pressure suffered by a human being or other animal."
e.g I've been under under a lot of stress lately.
So,you have to use "much" here.